# How to edit an XML file through .bat file?

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd

I want to add a specific configuration (web.config) xml file at a particular location, say "C:\home\dota". The configuration file has a `<configurations>` tab, and just below that, I want to enter this configuration for enabling CORS.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

How can I achieve this using Windows batch file, please help me in this regard.

Comment: `bash` and `batch` are two completely different things.

Comment: sorry, I meant batch file.

Comment: A cmd script is a ghastly tool with which to edit an XML file. Yes, you can put a screw in using a hammer, but it is not the right tool. Is there any chance of stepping up to Powershell or VBS? Better yet, Python or Perl.